# Can training and evaluation sets be the same in predictive analytics?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, data-mining, prediction

I'm creating a model to predict the probability that customers will buy product A in a department store that sells product A through Z. The store has it's own credit card with demographic and transactional information of 140,000 customers.

There is a subset of customers (say 10,000) who currently buy A. The goal is to learn from these customers 10,000 customers and score the remaining 130,000 with their probability to buy A, then target the ones with the highest scores with marketing campaigns to increase A sales.

How should I define my training and evaluation sets?

**Training set:**

Should it be only the 10,000 who bought A or the whole 140k customers?

**Evaluation set:** (where the model will be used in production)

I believe this should be the 130k who haven't bought A.

**The question about time:**

Another alternative is to take a photograph of the database last year, use it as a training set, then take the database as it is today and evaluate all customer's with the model created with last year's info. Is this correct? When should I do this?

Which option is correct for all sets?

Comment: And no, training and evaluations sets can't be the same thing. They can be part of the same set, but they shouldn't include each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The training set and the evaluation set *must* be different. The whole point of having an evaluation set is guard against over-fitting.

In this case what you should do is take say 100,000 customers, picked at random. Then use the data to try and learn what is about customers that make them likely purchase A. Then use the remaining 40,000 to test how well you model works.

Comment: Couldn't I take the 10,000 who bought A to create the model and evaluate the remaining 130,000 with the resulting model? Then they wouldn't be part of the same set.

Comment: Let's say you did that. First problem that you're going to have is that your model will think that no features are important. Nothing is important if everyone buys A. And even if, by some miracle, you came up with a decent model, how do you test it. Regardless of how good the model is, if nobody in the evaluation set has bought A then all the results are going to show that.

Comment: Got it, so I should include both customers who did and didn't buy A in the training set to create the model; as you said, I could pick 100,000 for the training set and 40,000 for the testing set, at random.

With "evaluation" set I'm referring to the group where I want to use the model in production. Could this be the same 140,000 set of customers? maybe on a later date when their purchase history has changed?